# Wamp não inicia o mysql quando reinicia o PC

Tags: mysql, wamp

Sempre que reinicio o PC, meu Wamp não abre o **Mysql**.
Tenho que reinstalar e acabo perdendo meus bancos. 
O servidor do wamp abre, mas o ícone fica amarelo.
isso aconteceu após eu instalar **Python/Django** e **Nodejs**. Nâo sei qual exatamente pois instalei seguido os dois e não testei o **Wamp** antes. lembro que durante a instalação, tive que alterar um arquivo do windows, que no final tinha `/wamp`. e coloquei `/python`. mas não me recordo a onde fiz isso.. e não consegui achar para testar.

Alguem tem a resposta pra isso ? :)

**apache_error.log**

```
[Thu May 21 19:22:39.022079 2015] [core:alert] [pid 15120:tid 968] [client ::1:49826] C:/wamp/www/PROJETOS/orientacao-objeto/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Thu May 21 19:22:39.048095 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 15120:tid 968] [client ::1:49826] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/Apache24, referer: http://localhost/projetos/
[Thu May 21 19:22:39.049096 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 15120:tid 968] [client ::1:49826] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/Apache24, referer: http://localhost/projetos/
[Thu May 21 19:22:39.050097 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 15120:tid 964] [client ::1:49827] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/Apache24, referer: http://localhost/projetos/
[Thu May 21 19:22:39.052100 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 15120:tid 960] [client ::1:49828] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/Apache24, referer: http://localhost/projetos/
[Thu May 21 19:22:39.053100 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 15120:tid 956] [client ::1:49829] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/Apache24, referer: http://localhost/projetos/
[Thu May 21 19:23:02.873965 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 15120:tid 936] [client ::1:49840] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/Apache24, referer: http://localhost/denis-manzetti/
[Thu May 21 19:23:02.874966 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 15120:tid 944] [client ::1:49841] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/Apache24, referer: http://localhost/denis-manzetti/
[Thu May 21 19:23:02.874966 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 15120:tid 936] [client ::1:49840] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/Apache24, referer: http://localhost/denis-manzetti/
[Thu May 21 19:23:02.875967 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 15120:tid 968] [client ::1:49842] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/Apache24, referer: http://localhost/denis-manzetti/
```

Comment: Verifique qual o erro de inicialização do MySQL nos logs que ficam geralmente em `C:\wamp\logs`.

Comment: Editei a pergunta, estes são os ultimos da lista, pode conferir o arquivo completo no link: http://pastebin.com/DjsivSnA

Comment: Esse pastebin contém o log de acesso, crie um com o **apache_error.log** também.

Comment: Como está o seu arquivo de configuração do apache?

Comment: Vc tem algum conflito de portas? Chegou a conferir? Que versão do Windows é essa?

Answer (score 0):

Mano, seguinte: Estava com o mesmo problema e os comentários de vocês me ajudaram a resolver o problema. To com a versão mais nova do wamp. E sempre que reinicio o pc ele da esse problema.
Problema: Toda vida que reinicia o pc, o wamp não sai do laranja.
Solução: Clique com o botão esquerdo do mouse, vá em mysql e abra com algum editor de texto (bloco de notas por exemplo) e verifique os erros, provavelmente será a porta usada pelo mysql (3306), troque a porta do mysql para 3307, restart o wamp e tente conectar. "É pra da certo"!

OBS: Caso não dê certo, troque novamente pela porta 3306 e restart novamente, vai funcionar normal, pois o erro se trata apenas de uma falta de comunicação com a porta do mysql.